# list subdirectories files without showing subdirectories using list.files R function

Tags: r, list

I want to list all files in the subdirectories of a directory without showing subdirectory paths in R. Here is my script:

```
list.files(path="path_to_directory", include.dirs = FALSE, recursive = TRUE,  pattern = ".fasta")
```

However, it still shows the subdirectories path like `folder1/filenameA.fasta` and `folder2/filenameB.fasta` but I want `filenameA.fasta` and `filenameB.fasta`.

Comment: Wrap in `basename()`?

Comment: @Richard Scriven it works! Thanks.